# Conan returning "ERROR: Invalid generator 'cmake'" when running conan install

Tags: c++, cmake, package-managers, conan

When running the following script in my c++ project:

```
cd cmake-build-debug/ || return
rm -rf conanBuild/
mkdir conanBuild && cd conanBuild
conan install ../.. --build=missing
```

I get the error message

```
ERROR: Invalid generator 'cmake'. Available types: CMakeToolchain, CMakeDeps, MesonToolchain, MSBuildDeps, MSBuildToolchain, NMakeToolchain, NMakeDeps, VCVars, QbsProfile, VirtualRunEnv, VirtualBuildEnv, AutotoolsDeps, AutotoolsToolchain, PkgConfigDeps, BazelDeps, BazelToolchain, IntelCC, XcodeDeps, XcodeToolchain, PremakeDeps
```

This used to run just fine, but after running a brew command to install a different package, brew also updated all my existing packages, including conan. I seemingly cant downgrade as brew only returns one version when running `brew search conan`.

Even [the docs](https://docs.conan.io/1/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_generator.html) clearly state that this should work.

As I couldnt find anything related to this when googling I'm coming here for help.

Does anyone know what the problem here may be?

Versions:

```
conan: stable 2.0.2
cmake: stable 3.26.0
Homebrew 4.0.9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are linking Conan 1.X docs (the 1 is in the URL)

You also have a green banner in the top of the page that reads:

> This document is for a "1.X" Conan version. Click here to see the Conan 2.0 documentation

The version you are using is 2.0.2 the docs are in https://docs.conan.io/2/ (or https://docs.conan.io). The `cmake` generator has been superseded long time ago in Conan 1.X in favor of `CMakeDeps` + `CMakeToolchain` and it has been completely removed in Conan 2.0

If the `brew` version is the problem, I'd suggest installing it from pip instead, something like `pip install conan==1.59`

Comment: `pip install conan<2.0` will always install the latest version 1 release

Comment: Thank you, I managed to install conan 1.59 using `brew install conan@1` and `brew link conan@1`. Not sure why it doesnt diaplay that version when using `brew search conan` though...